# Alternative to tshark library for exporting pcaps as csv

Tags: networking, packet-capture, centos

I have trouble installing tshark in a server running CentOS. Is there any alternative to tshark in exporting pcaps as CSV? I am trying to create a python script to run the export as csv command and analyze the data.

Comment: [Scapy](https://scapy.net) has a lot of features for loading and visualizing pcap dump files. Not sure how complicated it would get to let it output csv.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: what features do you need, how much may it cost.